# Security concerns about using Facebook implicit token for server side resource server OAuth2 authentication

Tags: security, authentication, oauth-2.0, facebook-javascript-sdk, single-page-application

I have poured over the OAuth2 docs and seen how the **Facebook Javascript SDK** uses **Implicit Grant**.

I am building a ReactJs application, which communicates with a PHP-Symfony API.

What I want to do is offer the "Login with Facebook" option on the frontend.
What I need on my PHP server is the Facebook user id and email and other data of the user so I can initially create a user record for them in my DB and then on returning visit, use the auth token to get that info again on the server and use it to match it to existing records and log the user in.

We have done this previously using the **Authorization Code Grant** method to redirect the frontend to our server, then to facebook and then back to us with the auth code. We then use that on the server with our **Secret Key** to get the **Access Token** and get the user info directly from Facebook to our server and then authenticate the user.

The redirection is a bit of a pain for a single page application.
Facebook's Javascript SDK handles a lot of that automatically, but uses **Implicit Grant**, returning an **Access Token** directly to the frontend.

What I want to know is, can I just send that **Access Token** to my server to do the same type of authentication that I did before? Or is that a massive security hole that I am opening up?

Comparing the two, the **Auth Code** from the **Authorization Code Grant** flow also goes via the frontend, but very quickly, not directly to JavaScript and is much shorter lived. So it feels much more secure. 
If intercepted in time and with matching state, it could be used to authenticate someone on our server, but not access someone's Facebook data directly.

Reusing the frontend **Access Token** from the **Implicit Grant** flow feels like it is open to messing with, but I can't put my finger on the exact scenario that would make it more vulnerable to attack. The token would potentially give people access to not only authenticating on our server but also to accessing people's Facebook info.

So this is ultimately a question of best practice and security.

We think that we should be able to implement our own popout window that does the **Authorization Code Grant** style flow and retrieves our server cookie which can then be used by the page that spawned it, but it is going to be tricky and most of the work seems to be done for the **Implicit Grant** method, if it is safe to use as we intend to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best Practices AND According to the [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.2)

> However, this convenience should be weighed against the **security
> implications of using implicit grants**, such as those described in
> Sections 10.3 and 10.16, especially when the **authorization code
> grant type is available**.

Comment: Thanks. That was really useful. Especially the part that says: "Any specification that uses the authorization process as a form of delegated end-user authentication to the client (e.g., third-party sign-in service) MUST NOT use the implicit flow without additional security mechanisms that would enable the client to determine if the access token was issued for its use (e.g., audience-restricting the access token)."

Comment: On the back of this advice, we have decided to implement **Authorization Code Grant** in our app. We will try pop out a window to do the redirect flow through and get the cookie or JWT and then use it on the parent to access our API.